# javascript async: Log the response from each action in the order it was called

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, promise

I'm trying to bone up on JS asynchrony, and am struggling with the following interview practice problem some of you might be able to shed some light on.

Given the following provided function (which we are not allowed to alter):

```
    function processAction(i, callback) {
     setTimeout(function() {
       callback("Processed Action " + i);
     }, Math.floor(Math.random()*1000));
   }
```

Write the function `triggerActions(count)` (which must call `proccessAction`) and the `callback(message)` function such that `triggerActions(3)` logs the following:

`Processed Action 1
Processed Action 2
Processed Action 3`

I'm unable to figure out how to get my actions to log in the same order they were started without changing the `processAction` function. I'm also unsure how to implement a function that will allow me to do so for an arbitrary number of actions. The closest I've managed to the correct functionality is like something below:

```
const printString = (x) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let time = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`${x} is resolved after ${time}.`);
      resolve();
    }, time);
  });
}
async function printAsync() {
  await printString('a');
  await printString('b');
  await printString('c');
};
```

Which produces:

```
a is resolved after 431.
b is resolved after 149.
c is resolved after 798.
```

Resources consulted so far:

--[callbacks/promises/await](https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/callbacks-promises-and-async-await-ad4756e01d90)

--[understanding async/await](https://medium.com/@rafaelvidaurre/truly-understanding-async-await-491dd580500e)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (which we are not allowed to alter):

What you can do then is create a wrapper function instead.

eg.

```js
function processAction(i, callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    callback("Processed Action " + i);
  }, Math.floor(Math.random()*1000));
}

function processActionWrap(i) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    processAction(i, function (str) {
      console.log(str);
      resolve(str);
    });
  });
}

async function test() {
  await processActionWrap(1);
  await processActionWrap(2);
  await processActionWrap(3);
}

test();
```

Answer (score 2):

Keith's answer led me to implement the following which seems to function correctly:

```
async function triggerActions(count) {
  let i = 1;
  for (i; i <= count; i++) {
    await processActionWrap(i);
  }  
}

function processAction(i, callback) {
  let time = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    callback(`Processed Action ${i} in ${time}`);
  }, time);
}

function processActionWrap(i) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    processAction(i, (str) => {
      console.log(str);
      resolve(str);
    });
  });
}

triggerActions(5);
```

Output:

```
Processed Action 1 in 841
Processed Action 2 in 15
Processed Action 3 in 346
Processed Action 4 in 331
Processed Action 5 in 314
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You could use some currying:

```
const trigger = (fn, max, count = 1) => () => max <= count && fn(count, trigger(fn, count + 1));

const triggerActions = max => trigger(cb => processAction(res => (console.log(res), cb()), 3)();
```

... but in an interview i would not try to impress with functional programing but would rather wrap `processAction` into a promise:

```
const triggerAction = i => new Promise(res => processAction(i, res));
```

So then you can `await` that easily, even in a loop...